# LibGDX light sensor data

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using LibGDX to make a desktop/android application. In part of my application I am checking the light sensor if it is android. This works fine for android except when I implement it into my LibGDX project I am confused as to how I can pass this data across.

```
SensorManager sm;
Sensor s;
float lux = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
s = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
initialize(new MyLibGDXMain(), cfg);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
lux = event.values[0];
}
```

I can retrieve my light sensor data here but once I initialize MyLibGDXMain I lose this data. If I add the SensorEventListener to that class I lose compatibility with the desktop version. So I have tried to create another constructor for the MyLibGDXMain to pass the lux value over but this only breaks whatever the LibGDX application is doing.

This question is not how to retrieve sensor data on android but rather
How would I go about getting this sensor data into my LibGDX main without breaking compatibility with the desktop project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create an interface between your application and the platform-specific code...

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

One way would be to create an Interface `LightSensorInterface` in your main project, containing a method `float getCurrentLux();`

```
public interface LightSensorInterface {
    public float getCurrentLux();
}
```

You then would have to create a class that implements that interface in your android project and one in your desktop project as well.

```
public class AndroidLightSensor implements LightSensorInterface, SensorEventListener {
    private float currentLux = 0;

    @Override
    public float getCurrentLux() {
        return currentLux;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        this.currentLux = event.values[0];
    }
}
```

Since you don't have a light sensor on your desktop application, the implemented method there could just return some fixed value.

And the implemented `getCurrentLux()` in the android project needs to return the lux value that you got the last time `onSensorChanged()` was called...

The constructor of your MyLibGDXMain() will need a reference to a `LightSensorInterface` and when initializing your app, you would pass the platform-specific class:

```
onCreate() {
     ....
    AndroidLightSensor sensor = new AndroidLightSensor(...);
    initialize(new MyLibGDXMain(sensor);
}
```

If you want to always have the current value, you need to fetch the current value within your render loop... hope you get what I mean...

Hope it helps.. ::)

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely try this out soon & get back to you! Just a few quick questions, & then I will be back for more to tell you if it worked or not.

It tells me to remove `@Override` on my `GetCurrentLux()` method. I don't know if it is something I did but it gives me an error(seems to work fine if I remove override). Secondly, should I create two separate classes AndroidLightSensor with the same name in my Android and Desktop folder? Or should I call the Desktop one DummyAndroidLightSensor? What is the standard practice for this? I am so happy I finally have a real use for interfaces.

Comment: Also want to build up my code the right way. Should I create an onResume and onPause seperately in my AndroidLightSensor and pass them into my MainActivity? Right now I made an AndroidLightSensor onResume to register the listener and then I pass that into my MainActivity. I know this is all preference but was looking for some organizational advice.

Comment: The "Remove @Override" seems weird. Did you forget the "implements LightSensorInterface? Usually it only says that when in the parent class that this class inherits from or in the classes of the interfaces, there is no such method... But I guess if you remove it and it still works fine that's ok... ;)

And right, you would put the `LightSensorInterface` into your main project somewhere. And within the Android project you can create your `AndroidLightSensor` and in your Desktop project create a `DummyDesktopLightSensor` class or whatever...

Comment: Does the class really need an `onPause()` and `onResume()`? And does it do so on every system? So you have the choice of just adding these two methods in your android class and have your MainActivity call it from its `onPause()` and `onResume()`... Or you could add the two functions `pause()` and `resume()` to your `LightSensorInterface` and then would have to implement it for each system. And you would call that method from within the methods in your main libgdx project... You are free to use either way, it mostly depends on the nature of what you are trying to interface with...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think the override was a glitch in Eclipse because a couple compilations later it made me readd it.